# Blender has problems rendering some parts of an imported FBX model

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I am a data scientist, with no knowledge on 3D modeling, and my goal is to make various rendering of a model by controlling the camera through a Python script. Writing the Python script was quite easy (great interface!) but I'm facing rendering problems and can't figure out how to tackle this.

The model has been made in some Autodesk software, with very simple forms (mostly cylinders/tubes). I have imported the corresponding FBX file. Blender has problems rendering *some* parts of it. The model probably need some cleaning… but it's actually rendered correctly in MS 3D Viewer (and I suppose, in the original Autodesk software), so there's likely a way to reach that in Blender without cleaning too much?

Here's a snapshot using the viewport's solid view:
[image: solid view]

Here's a snapshot using the viewport's render preview:
[image]

Here's a snapshot from MS 3D viewer:
[image]

I have tried:

- removing the hidden/unnecessary faces
- using some boolean union / split edge modifiers (but I might have chosen faces that were not meaningful)
- switching from shade smooth to shade flat
- changing the renderer for eevee or cycles, and playing with the parameters

The "cycles" renderer does not show these mistakes, but is quite CPU/GPU intensive and since I want to take +100000 captures, I'd rather avoid it.

Do you have any advice on what I can try?
Maybe there's another renderer in the add-ons that I can try?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure where's your problem, but sometimes you need to reset the split normals of imported fbx, you could try Properties panel > Object Data > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals Data. If it doesn't work, maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Is the model by any chance very far from the world origin ?

Comment: Did you export the textures/

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help me!  

@Gorgious was correct: my model was *very* far from the world origin! I've added a `body.matrix_world.translation` operation in my script to automatically fix this, and the rendering is now impeccable!

Comment: @FrançoisP. It's a very common floating point precision error :) Blender (and many other 3D softs) don't bode well with very high coordinates. You can also set the object origin to geometry, then clear the transforms

Comment: @Gorgious

I do not see how I can "set the object origin to geometry, then clear the transforms".
Do I set `obj.location` (they are all equal to (0,0,0)) to the mean of the vertex coordinates?
Then what is the property corresponding to the "transforms" so I can clear them? I've looked at `matrix_world`, `matrix_basis`, `matrix_local` and none of them seem affected when I change `location`.